# Change constraints value after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I add constraints programmatically to a view with this code in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
let top = isLandscape ? 30.0 : 5.0
let bottom = isLandscape ? 60.0 : 20.0

let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: top)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: bottom)
let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)

mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(mySubview)
self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
```

How can I apply the appropriate constaints when the device orientation changes? I read about setNeedsUpdateConstraints but didn't understood how to use it or if it even can help me.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should help:

```
override func willAnimateRotation(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
     self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

Now every time the device orientation changes, it will recalculate constraints and adjust if necessary

Comment: But I want to change the value of the constraint, as you can see the top and the bottom constrains do not have the same values in landscape

Comment: Write your code now into a function and call that function when orientation changes, instead of setNeedsUpdateConstraints(). But I think you'd have to remove the subviews and add them again in this case.

Comment: Do you need to add the view programatically? If you add it in the Interface Builder, you can hardcode constraints which you can create IBOutlets from and modify them easily

Answer (score 0):

First, create class-level variables / properties for your constraints. Then in viewDidLoad, set those constraints instead of creating new ones:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var mySubView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let top = isLandscape ? 30.0 : 5.0
        let bottom = isLandscape ? 60.0 : 20.0

        topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: top)
        bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: bottom)

        leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)
        trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: mySubview, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)

        mySubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(mySubview)
        self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])

    }
}
```

Then, when you want to change the values:

```
    let top = isLandscape ? 30.0 : 5.0
    let bottom = isLandscape ? 60.0 : 20.0

    topConstraint.constant = top
    bottomConstraint.constant = bottom
```